# Apostrophe show up as symbols when enter data in php

Tags: php, escaping, symbols, apostrophe, sanitize

Say I enter a comment from a form with this term for eg."john's cookhouse". It will show up as "john&#039;s cookhouse"

I am sanitizing the input going in and coming out with the following escape function.

```
function escape($string) {
    return htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}
```

For e.g `escape($_POST['comment']);

How can I make it so that an apostrophe is accepted?

Answer (score 1):

> I am sanitizing the input going in and coming out

Then you're doing it wrong.

Going in, you should be passing it to a prepared statement.

Coming out is when you should use `htmlentities` or a more fine-tuned function.

Always escape appropriately. Excessive escaping leads to double-encoding like you see here.

Comment: Wow, you are right. That worked. I removed the escape for input going in. Used it only for when it comes out. Now my question is, wouldn't someone be able to input sql injection if i don't protect the input going in the db? I am using prepared statement btw.

Comment: Reading from that link, I understand it better now.  I don't have to sanitize data going in the db; that is if I am using prepared statements. But I do need to sanitize it if getting the data from db. Good to know.

Comment: `you should be using mysql_real_escape_string` - WHAT?

Answer (score -2):

I am also having this kinda problem...

Just a minute ago, i've found the answer: `html_entity_decode($myString)`

Comment: unfortunately, you have got it wrong. Instead of constant decoding, you just shouldn't perform extra encoding.